# Why does associatedtype not conform to protocols defined in its constraining protocol?

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swift-protocols, associated-types

I'm trying to make my SwiftUI views more "Previewable" therefore I'm making them generic over their Store (ViewModel) so I can more easily mock them.

Consider the following example:

```swift
public protocol HomeViewStore: ObservableObject {
    associatedtype AnimatableImageStoreType = AnimatableImageStore

    var title: String { get }
    var animatableImageStores: [AnimatableImageStoreType] { get }
    var buttonTapSubject: PassthroughSubject<Void, Never> { get }
    var retryTapSubject: PassthroughSubject<Void, Never> { get }
}
```

```swift
public protocol AnimatableImageStore: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    var imageConvertible: Data? { get }
    var onAppear: PassthroughSubject<Void, Never> { get }
}
```

```swift
struct AnimatableImage<
    AnimatableImageStoreType: AnimatableImageStore
>: View {
    @ObservedObject private var store: AnimatableImageStoreType

    public init(store: AnimatableImageStoreType) {
        self.store = store
    }

    ...
}
```

```swift
public struct HomeView<
    HomeViewStoreType: HomeViewStore
>: View {
    @StateObject private var store: HomeViewStoreType

    public init(store: HomeViewStoreType) {
        self._store = StateObject(wrappedValue: store)
    }

    public var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(store.title)
            Button {
                store.buttonTapSubject.send(())
            } label: {
                Text("API Call")
            }
            .background(Color(.accent))
            .padding()
            Button {
                store.retryTapSubject.send(())
            } label: {
                Text("Retry")
                    .font(.monserrat(.bold, 14))
            }
            .padding()
            List(store.animatableImageStores) { animatableImageStore in
                AnimatableImage(store: animatableImageStore)
            }
        }
        .background(Color(.accent))
    }
}
```

The code gives me the following error messages:

[image]

My questions would be, why is HomeViewStoreType.AnimatableImageStoreType not conforming to AnimatableImageStore protocol when inside HomeViewStore protocol I'm constraining it to AnimatableImageStore protocol and the same goes for Identifiable which AnimatableImageStore conforms to?

Would appreciate if someone could show me a proper way to achieve this :)

Comment: Why `associatedtype AnimatableImageStoreType = AnimatableImageStore` and not `associatedtype AnimatableImageStoreType: AnimatableImageStore`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line doesn't constraint `AnimatableImageStoreType` to `AnimatableImageStore`:

```
associatedtype AnimatableImageStoreType = AnimatableImageStore
```

Replace `=` by `:` and it will work:

```
associatedtype AnimatableImageStoreType: AnimatableImageStore
```

Comment: I can not believe that I missed that, I wrote correctly that I wanted to constrain it, but I did not actually constrain it, thank you ! :)